# Realtime website using Icefaces

Tags: icefaces

Is there any real time  (internet) site that has a login form using icefaces. If yes, please give me a sample.

Comment: did you check the list of customers on the ICEfaces site?
http://www.icesoft.com/company/customers.html

Comment: You want to use the j_security_form with icefaces components? I tried it in the past but not found a way. I don't think it's even possible for the application server to understand an ice:form as the login form

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ? http://www.icefaces.org/main/resources/tutorials.iface

Comment: no.... i m not lookin for the above url.
i want a internet website that implememts icefaces for their login form authentication,